# Save memory for Complex PHP function

Tags: php, linux, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm using PHP to process data for about 10K users. Right now if I do them all together, it gives me a blank page (after processing about 3k users).

After checking the log, I found the function itself takes more than 500Mb to process and it's too much for my server to burden now.

Is there any ideas about how to alleviate this? Do I have to separate them into different group and process the users?

Thank you,

Comment: Could be a memory thing. Try with `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: It could be a memory thing or a max run time thing. Check your logs again.

Comment: Given that I can do 100K inserts in about 5 seconds on the cheapest hosting package known to man, I suspect you have buggy code.  The best way to handle this is to comment out some chunks of code.  Start with getting rid of almost everything, then allow it back in, one step at a time.  It does depend on what you are trying to achieve, but I cannot imagine 10K users would have more than 10MB data altogether.  Post some code if you want more help.  And upvotes.